# about org.apache.tomcat.util.net. Acceptor

Tags: tomcat

org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor

```
           // Loop if endpoint is paused
            while (endpoint.isPaused() && !stopCalled) {
                state = AcceptorState.PAUSED;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            }
```

why sleep 50 not 100 or other

Comment: The author had to choose an amount, which isn't too short (many processor cycles wasted) and doesn't take too long for the connector to restart after a pause.

Comment: Why it must be 50 milliseconds

Comment: It doesn't have to be.

Comment: How much should that be,I want to know why it is set to 50,cpu time slice is not a certain value,Why should the author set it to 50

Answer (score 0):

To choose an amount you have to answer the question: how fast do you want your `Connector` to resume accepting request after a [`Connector#resume()`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Connector.html#resume--) command has been issued? The author chose 50 ms, it is as good a choice as any other.

Remark that the code you cite is executed **only** if the `Connector` is paused and resumed through [JMX](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/monitoring.html), which happens extremely rarely. I can bet that, since this code was written, nobody ever had reason to change that amount.